# Confusion with pivot problem from Strang's Linear Algebra [P14 section 3]

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

This is the 14th problem in the 3rd section of the book: "Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Gilbert Strang.

The problem states: "Suppose   Column 1 + Column 3 + Column 5 = 0 in a 4 by 5 matrix with 4 pivots. Which column has no pivot? What is the special solution? Describe N(A)."

The solution is supposed to be: "Column 5 is sure to have no pivot since it is a combination of earlier columns. With
4 pivots in the other columns, the special solution is s = (1, 0, 1, 0, 1). The nullspace
contains all multiples of this vector s (this nullspace is a line in $R^5$).

I have no idea why column 5 would be free column, since while values in matrix of columns 1, 3, and 5 depend on each other I don't see a reason variables should(with variables I mean the matrix we are multiplying with, when finding N(A).
Is this not the correct interpretation, and what am I missing?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't understand your "*since* [...] I don't see a reason variables should" (i.e. why would this explain that). I don't even understand what you mean by "the variables should depend on each other" (although I understand what you call the variables).

Comment: The only thing you are missing is probably that a pivot can only occur on a column which is not spanned by the previous ones.

Comment: You don't need all this stuff to find $\ker A.$ Since there are 4 pivots the rank is $4$ hence the kernel has dimension $5-4=1.$ And the hypothesis $C1+C3+C5=0$ is equivalent to $(1,0,1,0,1)^t\in\ker A.$

Comment: I suspect you're thinking that column 3 could be free with the pivots in columns 1, 2, 4, and 5. There certainly are matrices like this. But then column 3 will have to be a linear combination of columns 1 and 2 because of the way row-echelon form is defined.